# Conditional Rewrite in Apache 2: are these two Identical?

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, apache2, conditional-statements

Can ...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder1/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder2/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder3/
RewriteRule (.*) / [R=301,L]
```

... be rewritten to ...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(folder1|folder2|folder3)/
RewriteRule (.*) / [R=301,L]
```

?

And if so, are they absolutey identical in functionality?
Suggestions/improvements are much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @Prix, that seems the case! If you put it as answer I'll +1 accept it!

Comment: You may make it shorter: `^/folder[1-3]/`

Comment: Moreover, note that in each case your URI must always end with a slash, if you want it to be optional change the ending slash, **/**,  to **/?**. The question mark, **?**, stands for **0** or **1** occurence of a literal that stands before it. In this case a slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same thing, the `|` stands for `OR` so if it starts with `/folder1/` or `/folder2/` or `/folder3/` do the redirect.

So yes it would be shorter and work out for your needs.

As Pekalski suggested you can make it shorter with:

```
^/folder[1-3]/
```

A few more examples and references can be found at:
http://semlabs.co.uk/journal/mod_rewrite-quick-reference-and-cheat-sheet